# Window and alert object/function not available in Underscore template?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am trying to access a variable called teams in my Underscore template and is proving to be one of the most difficult things I have ever had to do. But my question right now is - why can't I call alert() or window.alert() inside my template javascript code?

here is the template:

```
<script id="user-home-main-table-template" type="text/template">

    <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>

        <th>Club</th>
        <th>Sport</th>
        <th>Delete?</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>


    <%

    if(teams == null){
    alert('teams is null');   //alert is not defined
    window.alert('teams is null'); //window is not defined either
    var teams = {};
    }

    for(var i=0; i
    <teams.length; i++) { %>
        <tr>

            <td>
                <a class="font-big" href='/users/<%=user._id%>/teams/<%=teams[i]._id%>/teamDashboard'>
                    <%=teams[i].club %>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="font-big" href='/users/<%=user._id%>/teams/<%=teams[i]._id%>/teamDashboard'>
                    <%=teams[i].sport %>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-warning" onclick=window.userHomeMainTableView.deleteTeam('<%=teams[i]._id%>');>delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
    </tbody>
</table>
</script>
```

for some reason alert() and window.alert() are not available inside this template script. Is there a good reason for this?

Comment: client-side.... I am switching over to Handlebars

Comment: Please post the coffee if the Backbone view populating the template

Comment: Try inserting a `debugger` line to break the code while your template generates. This will help you resume the scope.

Comment: why on earth would you want to use an alert box inside a template? template should be used for presentation only.

Comment: he is probably using it as a means to try and debug the code.

Comment: yes to debug, and to see the full extent of what could be wrong

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a good reason for it.

Your template is executed with the `data` you pass into it.

From the [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#template):

> When you evaluate a template function, pass in a data object that has properties corresponding to the template's free variables

```
var compiled = _.template("hello: <%= name %>");
compiled({name: 'moe'});
=> "hello: moe"
```

So, when you send your data to the template, it does not contains a `window` property - nor should it!

If you need to debug the function execution, simply step inside the template execution during runtime. In Chrome, while in debug mode, you can "Step Into" by pressing `F11`.